# Issue with multichannel LM317 circuit

Tags: power-supply, lm317

I'm building a 4-channel 0-10v power supply for controlling a set of dimmable Meanwell LED drivers.  I'm basing my design off this circuit:

[image]

I simply repeated the same circuit four times on the same perfboard.  Three of the channels work mostly as expected, outputting 0-9v without load.  The forth channel on the other hand is outputting 11-15v.  I'm driving the supply with a 12v wall wort.

I've double checked the resistance across all of the resistors, everything matches up exactly with the working channels.  I'm pretty much at the limit of my electronic knowledge, any hints at what to even check next would be helpful.

Here are some pictures of the mess that I have created:

[image]
[image]

The black & yellow leads go to the potentiometers. The corner pins marked black/red are the input +/-.  The pins sticking out between the caps is the output.

Comment: Can you post some pictures of what you actually built?  It's not possible for a linear converter circuit to put out 15 volts with a 12 volt source, so there is definitely something strange going on here.

Comment: There is no way that an LM317 changed 12 V to 15 V. Maybe you got a wrong part, or somehow created an oscillator, but there's no way for us to speculate what happened without more information.

Comment: Instead of measuring the output voltage, you should measure the voltage difference between the input and the output. My guess would be that your LM317 is broken, and it is not able to control the output voltage, the input and the output are simply connected inside.

Comment: Check the voltages at every node of a good channel against the bad channel. Note voltages for both and check where (and why) thing start to go wrong.

Comment: You're silly not to get a better PCB prototyping board that provides traces! Ouch! Also, the board you're using makes it easy, by design, to just connect adjacent pads with solder bridges, instead of stringing jumper wires. You can use solder to de facto "route" a custom PCB among the squares.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful ideas.  I think I'm going to start by cleaning up the board by switching to something with traces (I forgot they existed, thanks for the reminder @Kaz)  I've got an extra LM317 that I will use instead, just in case it is a bad chip.

Comment: Have you measured the output of the 12V supply? If its a low quality unregulated wall wart, it might very well be putting out 15V, with no load applied.

Comment: When you use a potentiometer as a rheostat, connect the wiper to the unused terminal. This way, if the wiper has intermittent behavior, the device looks like a 10K resistor, rather than an open circuit. Basically, regard  the resistive element as being the main part in the circuit, and the wiper as an add-on which shorts out a portion of that element, creating a variable resistance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ceramic caps appears to be at a different offset to the others, and there looks like a corresponding dry lead on the other side of the board (4 holes above the 9 of 8097 on the pcb). Without the cap, there may be oscillation which you're reading as a higher peak voltage.